# bluetoothctl: using gatt menu commands in non-interactive mode

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

On my Raspberry Pi 4, I would like to use bluetoothctl in non interactive mode but cannot figure out how to access the gatt menu. The command should be something like "bluetoothctl gatt menu list-attributes" but this syntax doesn't work.

For info, in interactive mode one must type "menu gatt" to switch to gatt menu and then commands like "list-attributes" are available.

Thanks in advance !

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bluetoothctl` allows for the commands to be specified using a dot to indicate the hierarchy. e.g `gatt.list-attributes`

For accessing information with code BlueZ provides APIs using D-Bus bindings.

For example, to get all the information BlueZ has can be done like this:

```py
import pydbus
bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
obj_mngr = bus.get('org.bluez', '/')
mngd_objs = obj_mngr.GetManagedObjects()
for path, obj in mngd_objs.items():
    print(obj)
```

The API is documented at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

Examples are available at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test